# Does a woman goes back to be sefaradi after divorcing from a ashkenazi husband?

Tags: minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, divorce, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

So, my parents just got divorced. My mother was Sefaradi when single and my father is Ashkenazi. When my mother married my father she adopted all ashkenazi customs, including not eating kitniot on Pesach etc.

Now that they got divorced, can she go back to the nusach sefaradi, and eat kitniot on this Pesach, for example?

Comment: She should be sure to speak with her Rabbi for a final ruling. We aren't a rabbi and don't know all the facts of the case.

Comment: On the subject: If her father was a koen then only if she did not have children is she allowed to eat truna

Comment: Duplicate of [What customs does a divorced/widowed woman follow? (Ashkenazi/Sfardi — hers or her ex-husband's?)](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56310/5151)

Comment: I would assume yes with hataras nedarim

Comment: If the analogy with trumah applies, then if she had children then she would have to stay with the customs of the husban in the same way the children are required to do.